# Scraping stocks - output in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, web-scraping

So here is my problem. I am trying to output my scraping results in a GUI using tkinter in python. The code i use works in the shell, but when i use it with tkinter it doesnt Here is my code.

```
import sys

from tkinter import *

from urllib.request import urlopen

import re


def stockSearch():

    searchTerm = userInput.get()
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+searchTerm+"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urlopen(url)
    htmltext = str(htmlfile.read())
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+searchTerm+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

    outputStock = str(["The price of ", searchTerm, "is ", price])

    sLabel2 = Label(sGui, text=outputStock).pack()

sGui = Tk()
userInput = StringVar()

sGui.geometry("450x450+200+200")
sGui.title("Stocks")

sLabel = Label(sGui, text="Stocks List", fg="black")
sLabel.pack()

sButton = Button(sGui, text="LookUp", command = stockSearch)
sButton.place(x=200, y=400)

uEntry = Entry(sGui, textvariable=userInput).pack()


sGui.mainloop()
```

If i input a search for Google (GOOG) for example, I return this:

"The price of GOOG is []"

However, if i use the same code, but i print the result in a shell as opposed to using tkinter, i get the price as it should.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your code isn't properly handling case. If you search for "goog" the value shows up. The problem is this line:

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+searchTerm+'">(.+?)</span>'
```

If you type "GOOG", the regex becomes:

```
<span id="yfs_l84_GOOG'">(.+?)</span>
```

However, the html that is returned doesn't have that pattern. Doing a case-insensitive search should solve that problem:

```
pattern = re.compile(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Also, there's no need to create a new `Label` every time -- you can create the label once and then change the text each time you do a lookup.

Comment: You mentioned that i could simply change the label, rather than make a new one, how would this be done?

Comment: @Blake: `the_label.config(text="the new text")`